# Adding custom images over countries on Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm new to geopandas and I want to add my own images on top of the specific countries that are in my dataframe. I created a sample image for clarification. I want to add coke.jpg to the United States, pepsi.jpg to the Russia and so on.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

[image: Sample image].

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! On this site, questions are required to be about narrowly focused programming problems, and you need to post an earnest attempt at solving the problem. We're not here to write your code for you. See the guide to [ask]. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think this will work easily with geopandas, since it requires georeferenced coordinates for your images which sounds tricky (ofc not impossible) for jpgs.

however you could use the underlying matplotlib subplot and annotate an image on that.

see my code below, inspired by this source
https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-insert-an-image-a-picture-or-a-photo-in-a-matplotlib-figure/

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

# load example image
with cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg') as image_file:
    image = plt.imread(image_file)

# load example map
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

f, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot example image
# specify extent of png on canvas
# use zorder to force image to be in the upper layer
im = ax.imshow(
    image,
    extent=(-20, 20, -20, 20),
    zorder=1
)
# plot map
world.plot(ax=ax, zorder=0)

# plot map
plt.show()
```

[image]